# Storing sensitive information in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I did not find a suitable answer in the previously asked similar questions on SO, so here goes; my vuejs webapp involves client side decryption of some pre-encrypted data, which involves the user to enter the decryption key. To prevent asking for the key repeatedly, I am thinking of temporarily storing the key in one form or another in vuex. What are the security concerns I should look out for? Also what is the best strategy to store the key in vuex? Reiterating the first point, there is no HTTP requests involved in the process, the encrypted data is already loaded and the decryption takes place in the client itself.

I am aware that even in production mode a skilled person can find the values stored in vuex, so how do I obfuscate the key?

Comment: Vuex data is stored in-memory only for the life of the page. What sort of data-leaks or attacks are you worried about?

Comment: @Phil, my concern is regarding developer console, one way or the other vuex data might be accessible from the console, production build may make the process quite difficult, but it should be possible to extract such data since, to my knowledge, vuex stores the data as it is without any kind of obfuscation

Comment: But the user is the one that gives you the key so what's the concern if they can access it in the console 

Answer (score 3):

The key can be exposed in 2 main ways

1. Your site has an XSS vulnerability, and is running malicious js. Prevent XSS.
2. A malicious user has physical access to the user's device. Log out the user, or delete the key from memory, after X minutes idle.

Comment: XSS is one of my concerns. I figure vuex data can be accessible by javascript injection programs like greasemonkey or tampermonkey. what can be done to protect from those?

Comment: Those are browser extensions, I don't think you can affect them in anyway from JS. At the least, warn the user to disable these extensions before submitting the key.

Comment: We had a pentester team review our VueJS code before going to production. They didn't find `vuex` s vulnerability. If the attacker has access to the client computer/memory they could exploit much more things than just `vuex`.